# Migrate from EXTJS To Another framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs

Hi guys I have EXTJS project and I want to migrate to a free open source JS framework that can use the  EXTJS code. Is it possible ? I have read about Reactjs and Modus but there is no many examples about that.
[this is  the link](https://moduscreate.com/blog/extjs-to-react-migration-to-open-source/)

can any one help me ? I know this not the right place to ask this general question. I have tried Quora but there is no answer.
I appreciate your help

Comment: Good question !!
By migrate you mean you want to create extjs like components on your own into other fw OR by using extjs(code & components) inside another framework ?

Comment: yes I mean using extjs(code & components) inside another framework

Comment: Most likely Ext-react fw should work but I wasnt able to execute it properly. Or maybe you 'll have to find some way such that parent container is of reactjs and it should hold extjs's executable child container.

Comment: Ext-react is not free and open source, correct?   He also said "use the extjs code".  so it sounds like a plugin clean-room implementation of extjs that is open source.  I don't think that exists at the moment.   The folks at Modus were putting together a framework that was feature compatible but would not be a plug-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think (actually I am sure) you are going to find a plug-in replacement for ExtJS that will use the code that was developed using the ExtJS library.

I don't want to speak for the people a Modus but from what I remember they were showing that much of what ExtJS offers is available using existing open source tools more specifically React. You can talk to the people at Modus and they could rewrite your software using opensource tools and they may be able to leverage some of the existing code.